# Why does this bash for loop only iterate once?

Tags: bash

```
for i in {1...50000}; 
do 
  $(sudo lsof -Pni | cut -f 1 -d ' ' > fd_history/$(date +"%H-%M-%S")); 
done
```

It is supposed to pipe the output of lsof into a file named after the current timestamp (only the first token each lsof output line). Each lsof takes several seconds to run since there are lots of files open.

The loop quits after the first iteration instead of continuously running lsof. Why? (I'm typing this line directly into my console by the way.)

Comment: Two dots. `{1..50000}`

Comment: Unbelievable, that fixed it.

Comment: You probably don't want the `$(...)` notation; it executes the command inside, captures the output, and then tries to run the command in the output.  Fortunately, you've sent the standard output to a file, so there won't be anything to execute, but removing the notation saves you a little time (barely measurable, but...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra dot there: `{1...50000}` should be `{1..50000}`; the first is not expanded in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `seq`.

```
for i in $(seq 50000); 
do 
  $(sudo lsof -Pni | cut -f 1 -d ' ' > fd_history/$(date +"%H-%M-%S")); 
done
```

Or

```
for i in {1..50000}; 
do 
  $(sudo lsof -Pni | cut -f 1 -d ' ' > fd_history/$(date +"%H-%M-%S")); 
done
```